# JQuery method not giving the expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thiis is my code:

```
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
alert( $("p").css("background-color"));
```

The alert is returning `undefined` instead of the color.

I tried on both Google Chrome and Firefox. I have extracted this from the w3c website and in their example, it works (I am even using the same jQuery version).

Comment: try to use `backgroundColor` instead

Comment: Do you have a `P` element in the DOM?

Comment: Did you add jquery js library

Comment: Seems working here https://jsfiddle.net/u2eLngan/. It will give undefined only if you don't have `p` element see https://jsfiddle.net/u2eLngan/2/

Comment: I literally copy pasted your code and it runs fine, the problem must lie somewhere else, do you have some more code? https://jsfiddle.net/3hLffwnd/

Comment: Do you have a $(document).ready in your JS file ?

Comment: You need to create a complete, minimal and verifiable example. Showing us the jQuery is a good start, but in order to see how it's used in your code, we need to see how you load the jQuery and where it fits into your html.

Comment: the P element was created after this instruction, that is why it wasn't working. thanks for answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you're calling that code before jQuery loads, or you don't have a `<p>` tag in your document at the time the code is executed.

To test the first case, move the script to the window's onload event handler. This code will be run only after all scripts have been loaded.

```
window.onload = function(){
  if(window.jQuery){
    $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
    alert( $("p").css("background-color"));
  }
  else{
    alert("jQuery is not loaded");
  }
}
```

If the alert `jQuery is not loaded` opens, you've identified the problem

To test the 2nd case, just be sure to include a `<p>` tag in your document before you try to change its CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Works perfectly fine in this JSFiddle.

```js
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
alert( $("p").css("background-color"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
test
</p>
```

Verify that you have a `<p>` tag in your HTML (like in my fiddle), and check if you have JQuery included, like so:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I'm partially agree with Turnip, perhaps additional example without `<p>` element in the DOM to reproduce the original bug will be better. But I still chose to upvote, the downvotes are out of place here

Comment: I added some explanations about my JSFiddle and why it works. But an example speaks louder than words most of the time, especially a very small working example. Thank you for the heads up, I will explain a little more my answers from now on.

Answer (score 2):

try this instead of your script.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
               $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
        alert( $("p").css("background-color"));
            });
        });
```

for html try this

```
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
```

this is basic Javascript. you should need to define which html property you want to change using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included JQuery source in the head tag.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code's working fine on JSFiddle. 
checkout: [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/afzg2p8a/)

Comment: OP has jQuery included otherwise an error would be thrown

Answer (score -2):

never mind, I found the reason it isn't working. I created the `p` AFTER this instruction, so it was actually selecting nothing.

Comment: A lot of people here put effort for you with correct and valid answers, you should accept one of them. This is not a case of self-answering question

Comment: You should probably accept @beetlejuice 's answer rather than adding your own